# Error in broadcast notification with Pusher and Laravel echo

Tags: pusher, laravel-5.5, laravel-echo

I want to broadcast my notification with Pusher and Laravel echo on a private channel.

My bootstrap.js file like below

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '5c3621c15520b7e2fb02',
    cluster: 'ap2'
});

Pusher.log = function(message){

    window.console.log(message)
}
```

and my notification.vue file like below

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.listen()
        },
        props: ['id'],
        methods: {
            listen() {
                Echo.private('App.User.' + this.id)
                    .notification( (notification) => {
                        alert('new notification')
                    })
              }
        }
    }
</script>
```

my BroadcastServiceProvider.php like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {

        Broadcast::routes();

        Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {
            return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
        });
    }
}
```

In the console it gives a error like below

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 334.3086157
Pusher : No callbacks on private-App.User.1 for pusher:subscription_error
if I changed BROADCAST_DRIVER=driver
```

it gives a error like below

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 
Pusher : No callbacks on private-App.User.1 for pusher:subscription_error
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know exactly where the issue is without seeing the entire codebase, however I can recommend the following blog post over at the Pusher blog that takes you through the entire process that has worked for me in the past.

https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should change `BROADCAST_DRIVER=driver` to `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` in your `.env` file.